# Quiz isn't working as intended

Tags: python-2.7

Keep getting syntax error.
I keep getting........
**CODE:**

```
answer = "b"
question = "1) Who made the game Grand Theft Auto 5??\nPlease choose from  the following and write a letter: \n◘ A)Viral\n◘ B)Rockstar Games\n◘  C)Madfinger\n◘ D)Gameloft"
print(question)
guess=input().lower()
name=input("Please enter your answer: ")
if guess ==answer:
    print("Correct")
    score = score + 1
    print("Score:")
    print(score)

else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: what do you want here? can you show us some output?

Comment: The output is that it doesn't display "Please enter your answer".

Comment: @Whitefret In order to display it, I have to press ENTER but I don't want it to. I just want it to print it without pressing anything :/

Comment: well, didn't see that double input. just write: `question=input("Please enter your answer: ")`

Comment: You use `input` twice. No one can tell why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never use name, so why not removing it?

```
answer = "b"
question = "1) Who made the game Grand Theft Auto 5??\nPlease choose from  the following and write a letter: \n◘ A)Viral\n◘ B)Rockstar Games\n◘  C)Madfinger\n◘ D)Gameloft\n"
print(question)
guess=input("Please enter your answer: ").lower()
if guess ==answer:
    print("Correct")
    score = score + 1
    print("Score:")
    print(score)

else:
    print("Wrong")
```